# Rails, Devise, Validatable not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have Devise set up with :validatable on my simple app, but I can't seem to get the registration sign-up form to stop if it caught an error.

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
...
end
```

As of now, I have a sign-up form with standard name/email/password/age fields, and everything works fine when I submit the form that doesn't fail.

But, if I try to create a new user that I know would fail (ex. create a user with an e-mail that already exists), it will still try to create the user, and instead of redirecting back to the sign-up form, it will continue to load the next page as if it was a valid user! Of course, at this point, I get an error because it tries to load up a page with 'current_user' code, and the user doesn't exist.

Where do I even begin to track this down? Not sure if it's the way I installed Devise, or something else?? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used validatable, but you could always just roll w/ some of your own validations:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
validates :email, presence: true
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, message: "valid email please"
```

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal yes. you can set any conditions you want. You can also write a custom validation method using `validate`. Open a new question for validating min password length and someone will show you how. It's not difficult.

Comment: Ok, thankyou. It seemed to me that without validatable it was not working, so i included it in my user model anyway. working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

About format of email, I recommend you use devise.rb.
There you can set a regex to email, no need put in model.

```
 config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/
```

[Devise's Issue Explanation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/1016#issuecomment-23546009)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devise's email validation in non-devise models:

```ruby
class UserRegistration < ApplicationRecord
  validates_format_of :email, with: Devise.email_regexp
end
```